# What is the difference between C++ memory management and .NET memory management?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

What is the difference between C++ memory management  and .NET memory management ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++, you can either allocate objects with static storage so they are around for the whole program, allocate them on the stack when they are local to a function (in which case they are destroyed when the containing block exits), or allocate them on the heap (in which case they are only destroyed when you say so by explicitly calling the appropriate de-allocation function). Heap memory is allocated as raw memory with `malloc` and released with `free`, or allocated and constructed into an object with `new`, and then the object destroyed and the memory released with `delete`.

C# provides an illusion of infinite memory --- you cannot free memory explicitly, only allocate memory and construct an object with `new`. Instead the GC reclaims the memory for objects you can no longer access so that it can be reused for new objects.

In C++, class destructors are run when an object is destroyed. This gives each object a chance to release any associated resources whether they are more objects, or external resources such as file handles or database handles.

In C#, you must explicitly manage the release of non-memory resources by calling a release function. The `using` facility allows you to get the compiler to call `Dispose()` automatically for you, but this is still separate from the object lifetime --- the memory for the object is reclaimed when the GC system decides to (which may be never).

In C++, facilities like `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr` with older compilers) allow you to pass the responsibility of destroying heap objects over to the C++ runtime by reference-counting the objects. When the last instance of `shared_ptr` that references a given object is destroyed, then the referenced object is destroyed too and its memory reclaimed. This avoids many of the pitfalls associated with manual memory management.

Comment: In C++, you should not use `malloc()`/`free()`, but ottherwise this is an excellent summary. `+1` from me.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any meaningful difference in memory usage between C# and C/C++?
Can you get close RAM usage? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu there will be a memory usage difference, and a performance difference between C++ and C# because the code will be completely different: idiomatic C# is quite different from idiomatic C++. You would need to measure for any particular case.

Answer (score 6):

In .NET, memory is treated different than all other resources: While you have to take care of releasing all resources you need, you don't have to worry about memory.

In C++, you have to take care to release *all* resources you use, including dynamically allocated memory. However, C++ employs a number of tools and techniques (namely automatic scope-based allocation/deallocation and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) to help you with this. In a decade of writing C++ code, I have rarely ever (read: on average less than once per year) manually freed memory and if so, it was in a RAII handle class.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there is a whole lot less to worry about.

When you want to work with an object in C#, you can simply create it; and once you're done with it, you don't have to do anything else. A background worker (the Garbage Collector) will clean it up behind the scenes when it realises you're not using it any more.

In vanilla C++, there aren't any background processes running to clean up memory. This means that, any time you manually allocate memory (which is a lot of the time), you are responsible for deleting it once you're finished using it. Care must also be taken to ensure you don't delete the same thing twice.

A note on the C# side of things: This doesn't mean you can completely ignore how memory works. It's very helpful to know what happens behind the scenes. In general, though, you won't have to worry about it much.

**Edit:** As GMan notes below (if I'm understanding him correctly), you can deal with memory management in C++ by letting every allocation be scoped, and thus the C++ environment will look after allocation and deletion for you. In that sense, you again have to understand how C++ allocates and deletes in order to not run into troubles.

Comment: I'm almost never responsible for having to delete something I allocate; I'm only responsible for putting it into an appropriate container.

Comment: With proper coding style, you don't have to worry much about memory in C++ either

Comment: Your edit seems self-defeating, it sounds like you're trying to make C++ memory management look hard. All you have to understand is, if you use an automatically (stack) allocated object, it'll have it's destructor run...automatically. Any memory management is done in a container that, in the end, will always have it's destructor run, where you can do any clean-up. And there are tons of pre-made classes to do this for you, in the standard library, in boost, and around the web.

Comment: @GMan: +1 - Very true. I would still hold that memory management in C++ isn't as "magic" as it is in C#, and so requires a much better understanding of how memory is being allocated.

Comment: It's not only within scopes. Smart pointers can be freely copied so that the object they refer to outlives their scope, fully automating memory management. But, yes, C++ does allow manual memory management, and doing this might be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

some c++ open source choosed to create their own memory gabrage collector like V8 javascript engine to avoid all problems of memory leaks.